# Azure worker role becomes unresponsive after internal tcp connection with web role

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, azure, azure-worker-roles

I'm posting the question that first appears [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/ffa17157-6e54-405c-8ad0-43d97990d2d7/#b80a516a-5f0f-42ba-bdf1-02a291689494) because it seems that it is dead on the Microsoft forums. Plus, Stack Overflow is better. :-P

I'm hosting a TCP endpoint in a worker role on Azure --

```
var _breadcrumbServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(BreadcrumbService));
var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
var externalEndPoint = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["shuttles"];
_breadcrumbServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IBreadcrumbService), binding, String.Format("net.tcp://{0}/BreadcrumbService", externalEndPoint.IPEndpoint));
```

And I get two thrown exceptions --

```
System.InvalidProgramException  -  Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program
```

and

```
Unhandled exception: System.Runtime.CallbackException: Async Callback threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorBehavior.HandleErrorCommon(Exception error, ErrorHandlerFaultInfo& faultInfo)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.HandleError(Exception error, ErrorHandlerFaultInfo& faultInfo)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.HandleError(Exception error)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
```

It doesn't always happen -- sometimes Azure is perfectly happy.

Help!! Thanks.

Comment: I saw the same exact issue with data explorer, reducing the connection pool for odata calls which seems to have stopped this from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! It appears there's an issue with WCF hosted in a worker and IntelliTrace. Disabling IntelliTrace solved it.